# Prove $n \mid x + y \implies n \mid x - y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, solution-verification

I would like to prove following proposition

> $$n \mid x + y \implies n \mid x - y $$

Attempt:

$$kn = x + y, k \in \mathbb Z $$

Adding $y - y$ to the right side gives

$$kn = x + y - y + y = x - y + 2y$$

Which means

$$n \mid \bigl(x - y\bigr) + 2y$$

Hence $n \mid x - y$. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: $3$ divides $7+2$ but not $7-2$.

Comment: Did you even try any examples? $3$ divides $2+1$ for instance.

Comment: $n\mid x+y$ does not imply $n\mid x$ and/or $n\mid y$ - e.g. $5|12+13$ but neither $12$ nor $13$.

Comment: Have you actually thought about the problem? Posting an "attempt" which isn't even coherent doesn't exactly inspire confidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.

How do you know $n\mid 2y$? If that would be true than your statment would hold.

Say $5\mid 7+3$ but $5\nmid 7-3$.